# How to separate contents of a file into columns based on keyword using Bash

Tags: bash, grep

I have a `file.txt` that has contents in the following format:

```
co001 done
co002 done
co003 not run
co004 running
```

I want to read the `file.txt` and sort the lines into columns based on whether they contain "done", "not run" or "running" and display the following on screen

```
co001 done     co003 not run     co004 running
co002 done
```

So far I know I can use grep to extract the "done" or "not run" lines, but I don't know how to sort the grep results into columns. I figured that the "column" command will help somehow, but cannot think of how to go about doing it.

This should be an one-liner thing right?

Comment: Would you please try: `paste <(grep -v "not run" file.txt) <(grep "not run" file.txt)`.

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks a lot tshiono! Do you mind putting it as an official answer so I can mark it as answered? I've edited the question a bit, but your answer still answers it. Maybe you can use ````paste <(grep "done" file.txt) <(grep "not run" file.txt) <(grep "running" file.txt)```` for your answer.

Comment: Your question is tagged [bash], so the use of the *process substitution* (e.g. `<(...)` ) is proper, just be aware that is a bash-only idiom. (a *bashism*)

Comment: @Jacek thank you for the prompt feedback. I'm ready to post it as an official anwer, but let me clarify one thing. Your comment includes the key word `done` but your updated question does not. Which will be correct?

Comment: @tshiono I realized that I used the word "run" in the question when in my actual files it's using the word "done". I've edited the question to use "done", "not run" and "running", just to be consistent with our discussion here.

Comment: @Jacek thank you for the direction. I've posted the answer accordingly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about combining the `paste` command with the process substitution provided by `bash`:

```
paste <(grep "done" file.txt) <(grep "not run" file.txt) <(grep "running" file.txt)
```